# update http with successful login

Tags: php, database, http, authentication

I created a webpage that has a container that asks the user for username/password.

It uses a php file to check the database and if correct the php document (in a new page) just displays "login successful".

how do i change the original webpage, so that with a successful login - it displays the username in the updated container that once prompted for username/password?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, but here it goes.

It depends whether you want to use ajax or php to do it.

If you verify the login with ajax, you can simply just send the username back in the response and then simply change the html of the container to display the username using javascript.

If you reload the page, you can use the php to verify if the user is logged in and if he is logged in you can display the username in the container instead of the php.